# Parse file values using Java

Tags: java, nio

I'm new to Java and I would like to read this file content using Java:

```
Filename                          Type        Size     Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01   partition   524280   0       -1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02   partition   324280   0       -1
```

Can you show me some working example with Java 8?

This is the code so far:

```
private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Long>> totalSwap() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File("/proc/swaps");
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.err.println("/proc/swaps did not exist!");
            return null;
        }
        else if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            System.err.println("/proc/swaps is a directory, not a file.");
            return null;
        }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\/A-Za-z0-9]+)[\\s]+([a-z]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([\\-0-9]+).*");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/swaps"));

        String s = reader.readLine();
        while (s != null)
        {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.matches())
            {
                HashMap<String, Long> usageData2 = new HashMap<>();
                usageData2.put("allSwap", Long.parseLong(matcher.group(3)));
                usageData2.put("utilizedSwap", Long.parseLong(matcher.group(4)));

                data.put("First", usageData2);
            }
            s = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

        return data;
    }
```

I don't know how to read the FileName column. Finally I would like to get this result:

```
HashMap</dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01, HashMap<Size, 524280>
                                         HashMap<Used, 0>>
HashMap</dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02, HashMap<Size, 334220>
                                         HashMap<Used, 0>>
```

Can you help to solve this problem?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [show us your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GoBusto Post is updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get /proc/swaps using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651267/get-proc-swaps-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to split using a tab delimeter, if i remember correctly, linux is outputting using the tab  character.

I have had to improvise with youre code but it should be easy to plug your code back in.

See my example below:

```
private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Long>> totalSwap()
{
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Long>> data = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Long>>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\/A-Za-z0-9]+)[\\s]+[A-Za-z]+[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([\\-0-9]+).*");
    String s = "/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01\tpartition\t524280\t0\t-1\n/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02\tpartition\t324280\t0\t-1";
    String[] columns = s.split("\t");
    for (String line : columns) {
        HashMap<String, Long> usageData2 = new HashMap<>();
        usageData2.put("allSwap", Long.parseLong(columns[2]));
        usageData2.put("utilizedSwap", Long.parseLong(columns[3]));
        data.put(columns[0], usageData2);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw ema answered with a similar answer while I was writing an example. Apologies ema!

Comment: By the way this value `/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01` is always diffrent. I need also to get it and insert it into the final HashMap.

Comment: I understand it is always different.... I'm not sure I get your point. It would be in the final HashMap.

See the line:
data.put(columns[0], usageData2);

THat places it in the HashMap

I only hard coded the string as an example,

Do you want me to edit the code and re-p`lug your code back in so you can test?

Comment: Yes, please. I tested the code with different file values - it's not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use StringTokenizer with delimiter tab("\t") and retrieve required columns.

Comment: @PeterPenzov how about doing some reading on java basics? What happened when you applied the example from javadoc of Stringtokenizer?